# How to convert a database/schema from one vendor to another with Doctrine2 DBAL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, doctrine-orm

I have a database dump of an MySQL database and like to import this into databases of other vendors like sqlite or Postgres.

The bigger picture is: My application uses Doctrine 2 DBAL (w/o the ORM) and I like to make it compatible with other databases.

Is there a way to abstract the description of a schema via YAML or something else when I only use DBAL?

I found the SchemaManager inside the documentation [1]. Is this the only way for DBAL?

I already tried to dump the database with

```
mysqldump -u username -p --compatible=postgresql databasename > outputfile.sql
```

But when I imported the outputfile.sql I got errors from Postgres DB.

[1] http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-representation.html

Comment: Use a management tool like liquibase?

Comment: This looks like an interesting tool but since I this is a PHP project depending on JAVA is not the way to go here.